# Pendulum kinetic energy or radial velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, software

I was doing some pendulum simulation in python. My pendulum is point of mass attached to pivot with straight line without mass. I initiate movement at angle  $\theta=90\deg$ with $\omega = 0$

And I struggled to calculate linear velocity from omega I calculate every step.

*Sorry if I have used wrong tags*

#### Symbols

$\theta_0 = $ 30 or 90, I use degrees

$l=5 $, rope length

$m=1$, mass

$gravity = 9.81 $

$stepsize = 0.1$, this is step everytime I calculate omega and theta

#### Lagrangian

I stared with Lagrangian
$$L = T - V$$
$$T=\frac{1}{2}*m*v^2$$

$$V = mgh = mgl(1-cos(\theta))$$

and after solving lagrangian I ended up with two equations

$$
\omega = \omega_{old}  - gravity / l * sin(\theta_{old}) * stepsize
$$

$$
\theta = \theta_{old} + \omega*stepsize
$$

#### Friction

and after that I added simple friction to angular velocity

$$
\omega = \omega_{old}*(1-friction)  - gravity / l * sin(\theta_{old}) * stepsize
$$

#### Simulation is ok

Simulation works well, it swings from left to right almost infintely with same amplitude when `friction=0` and if I increase `friction=0.1` then it stopped after few swings.

$v = \sqrt{2*gravity*l*(1-cos(\theta))}$

after rearange and adding initial theta it looks like this

$v = \sqrt{2*gravity*l*(cos(\theta) - cos(\theta_0)}$

My energy calculations are correct. When I calculate `velocity` from this equation, total energy was constant during simulation $ E_t = E_p + E_k $

[image: Velocity calculated from mgh]

#### Energy problem

But it is now working for me when I try doing the same from omega.
I have tried few things and none of them worked, that means total energy was oscilating more or less.

Equation I have used for kinetic energy
$E_k = \frac{1}{2}m^2*v$

None of equation below worked for me.

$v = omega * l$

$v = rad(omega) * l$

$v = omega *\frac{2}{360} *\pi * l$

[image]

#### My questions:

1. How can I make it work? I want to show energy loss when decreasing omega. I know that this motion is nonlinear, but where I apply it ?
2. Is using degrees in **$\theta$** equation wrong?

Comment: Your equation $v = \sqrt{(2*gravity*l*h)}$ is not correct (if $l$ is a length and $h$ is height). And if possible you should use radians for $\theta$.

Comment: @Drjh hey, thanks I fixes this in question, I had similar formula in program, but this not the case. I Changed calculations to radians and it looks almost perfect, so Why is it big deal to convert deritive of position in degrees which should be radial velocity in degrees to radial velocity in radians?

Comment: If you are doing your simulation on a computer using a program which calculates the trig functions for you, the program probably assumes that the angles are in radians.